# background-size: cover on divs instead of background

Tags: css, html, background-image, inline

I have a number of divs of certain, knows sizes. The pictures that I would like to use as background differ in size so, I was thinking to use background-size:cover to make sure that the images inside sort of look good instead of being stretched or shown just a part of them.

But I cannot find the way to accomplish this. Another reason why this is not working is that I have the *need* to assign the background-image property inline only.

Does anyone have any idea on how to use background-size:cover on something that is actually not the whole viewport, but just a div?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post a jsfiddle or something similar showing what you have so far? You can definitely background-size inline for any element, and you can try playing around with "background-size: 100%".

Comment: yes :D plz do not come here without fiddles :D

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/UQP78/

Answer (score 1):

Try these styles:

```
background-size:contain;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:50% 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class with the following attributes, use this class with that div and make sure that for maintaining the aspect ratio you make width and height to 100% inside another div positioned relative

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: take a look at my comment... added the jsfiddle. is there no way to do it without wrapping?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Resize the frames in jsfiddle and you will observe that the image does not shrink below the min-width (set in percentages) while it can expand depending upon the space available

http://jsfiddle.net/UQP78/12/

http://jsfiddle.net/UQP78/10/

```
<div id="bg">
    <img src="http://www.faber04blog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/jquery" alt="">
</div>

#bg {
    position:fixed; 
    top:-50%; 
    left:-50%; 
    width:150%; 
    height:150%;
}
#bg img {
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    right:0; 
    bottom:0; 
    margin:auto; 
    min-width:25%;
    min-height:25%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UQP78/7/